# Displaying a lot of text in tables

Tags: html, css

I have a table, this table gets data from a server, and has a few fields,
The data from the server is plain text, but no limit on how many characters.

The table should not be over 900px wide.

[View example](http://plnkr.co/edit/T5AWCIOxtKfD94J6I47m?p=preview)

As you can see in my plunker some texts gets very long, so they take several rows, while some fit on the first row.
In my opinion, this is not readable at all, it's horrific.

And here's the real problem, since this should be printed some time, all text must be visible.
I have tried fooling around with some `fixed tables` and `overflow: hidden` properties, though this does make the table more attractive, a lot of text would be litterly unreadable

Basically what I am asking is if there are any tried methods for displaying (maybe) a lof of texts in tables, and have it readable?

**Edit**: Okey, as it seems this is the way to do it, there can be some stylig done, but nothing major. There's is one thing that bothers me though, and that's that the title field (field1) is pushed to the left so much.

I know I can set `width`, but that requires the table to be `fixed`, and that will cause problems, I need the table to be as dynamic as possible.

Is it possible to set priortiy on which cells the table will break words on first? So that maybe field 1 and 5 have a low priority, so those cells will be less likely to have line breaks?

Comment: I think that displaying a lot of text in tables isn't the correct approach. Tables are for short and concise text. That said, I don't see anything weird in the plunkr. Text wrapping in two lines is fine. You can try to even the columns so there is more than 3 words per line to make it more readable

Comment: I agree with @sailens on this one, that looks fine to me. However, if you need to represent even more data, consider having a hidden div that expands out below the table entry if clicked on.

Comment: @sailens How can I achieve 3 words per line?

Comment: You can define a `min-width` per cell and a `max-width` of 900px per table.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution, and the solution I have used in most of the projects i've done is to add a modal.

For example, if you have a pragraph of texts, the best thing to do it to display  a few words and then add a **View more** button which will open up a modal which will display the entire paragraph.

You can also try to add a **View** button in the end of each row in another column. Clicking this would open a modal which shows all the data in that row entirely. 
 
[image]
 
 
This way you can show some information in the table without making it ugly and also provide all the details in the table itself(although its not present in the table view).

Comment: I guess this would be the way to do it, although, this only works for the browser part. Opening a modal would be hard when it's printed on a piece of paper :d +1 (will use this on my main table)

Comment: in bootstrap, there are options where you can hide int he main view but make ur visible to the print view, in that case you can try  a different UI approach for the data

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me as well, although you may try alternating row colors... add the following rule to your css... you can of course change the color to whatever you like. I find it improves readability:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}
```